# How to chain RxSwift Singles in order

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

Let's say there are 3 methods I want to run in order and entry point is dependent on an integer(number).

```
func method1() -> Single<Void> {
    return .just(())
}

func method2() -> Single<Void> {
    return .just(())
}

func method3() -> Single<Void> {
    return .just(())
}
```

in regular Swift there would be switch like this:

```
func doThings(startingFrom number: Int) -> Single<Void> {
    switch number {
    case 0:
        method1()
        fallthrough
    case 1:
        method2()
        fallthrough
    case 2:
        method3()
        fallthrough
    default:
        print("Finished")
    }

    return .just(())
}
```

but considering method1(), method2() and method3 are Single I am thinking there should be a way in RxSwift to chain them without messing with their execution order.

I thought something like this but this works synchronous therefore there is no guaranteed execution order for methods.

```
public func doThings(startingFrom number: Int) -> Single<Void> {
    var actions: [Single<Void>] = []
    switch number {
    case 0:
        actions.append(method1())
        fallthrough
    case 1:
        actions.append(method2())
        fallthrough
    case 2:
        actions.append(method3())
        fallthrough
    default:
        break
    }

    return Single
        .zip(actions)
        .do(onSuccess: { _ in
            Log.debug("Finished")
        })
        .mapToVoid()
}
```

Sorry if I don't make sense, I'm quite new to RxSwift. Please correct me if something is wrong.

Comment: Since you're mapping to void anyway (indicating you're not really interested in the output of these singles), why not map them to `Completable` using `asCompletable`. With your curated list of `Completable`'s you can now do `Completable.concat(actions)`, which should execute them in order.

Comment: Just did that. Thanks! @SanderSaelmans

Comment: Single also has a `concat` operator. No need to convert to compietables first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution was very close. Just use `concat` instead of `zip` and you got it.

My bad, Single is missing the `concat` operator so you have to convert to Observable or Completable first. Here are a couple of options:

```
func doThings(startingFrom number: Int) -> Single<Void> {
    Observable.concat(
        [method1(), method2(), method3()]
            .dropFirst(number)
            .map { $0.asObservable() }
    )
    .toArray()
    .map(to: ())
    .do(onSuccess: { _ in
        print("Finished")
    })
}

func doThingsʹ(startingFrom number: Int) -> Single<Void> {
    Completable.concat(
        [method1(), method2(), method3()]
            .dropFirst(number)
            .map { $0.asCompletable() }
    )
    .andThen(.just(()))
    .do(onSuccess: { _ in
        print("Finished")
    })
}
```

Comment: Keeping everything same as in question, using Single.concat instead of Single.zip gives errors: 

`Referencing static method 'concat' on 'PrimitiveSequenceType' requires the types 'SingleTrait' and 'CompletableTrait' be equivalent

1. Where 'Self.Trait' = 'SingleTrait' (RxSwift.PrimitiveSequenceType)`

Comment: Right, of course because Single doesn't have `concat`. The specialized types are missing a bunch of operators like that. Convert to Observable or Completable first...